# Why does this journey to the moon take so long?

Tags: the-moon

I remember the Apollo missions and I'm pretty sure it took about three days to reach the moon.

India’s space agency is set to launch its homegrown Chandrayaan-3 moon mission from the southeastern island of Sriharikota, at the Satish Dhawan Space Centre on July 14 at 2:35pm local time (09:05 GMT).

A 43.5-metre (143-feet) Launch Vehicle Mark-III, or LVM3, launch rocket will blast the spacecraft into an elliptical Earth orbit before it loops towards the moon for a scheduled landing near the moon’s south pole around August 23.

Why 40 days instead of 3?

Comment: Since humans needing life support are not on board one can take a more efficient trajectory.

Comment: @JonCuster I wonder how much of the extra 37 days is actually necessary for the increase in efficiency, and how much is just conservative mission planning; trajectory and systems checks, corrections, etc. since there's no need to rush due to "perishables on board".

Comment: Their vehicle does not have anywhere near the performance of the Apollo vehicles.

Comment: FWIW, I have a Sage / Python script that makes 3D interactive plots of the trajectory of Chandrayaan-3, using data from JPL Horizons. See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/54240/16685

Comment: In effect, it is using the earth for gravity assist, to boost its orbit higher and higher. This is much more fuel-effiicient than a direct burn, but takes significantly longer.

Comment: China's Chang'e 4 took only 4 days to reach lunar orbit. It really depends on how much money you want to spend.

Comment: There are many things considered when planning a mission.  Hurry is often not one of them.  You need to consider the fuel efficiency, the lifetime of the payload, the sun angles at the destination if you are doing photography, where on the moon you want to arrive, etc.  So what if you don't have people aboard and it takes a month longer to get a better mission? -1

Comment: "homegrown" this is a very interesting formulation; to my ears, it kind of implies that "normally, we would use the standard rocket from XYZ, but they home-brewed their own DIY rocket instead" (taking it over the top for dramatic effect). ;)

Answer (score 42):

This is the trajectory of its predecessor, Chandrayaan-2:

[image: orbit raising before lunar capture]

Due to the low power of the spacecraft engine, it raises its orbit over multiple passes (and makes the most of the [Oberth effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect)).

As the orbit is raised, it takes longer to complete the orbit before the next burn. In addition, there appears to be a number of orbits where no burn takes place. Presumably this is to allow wriggle room to still achieve a rendezvous if an early burn fails (although it might be for more practical reasons, such as communications links, or perhaps even just so they happen during office hours).

I still feel it's worth noting the final trip to the moon "only" takes around six days.

Comment: I find it interesting that it orbits around Earth 3 times before conducting the next burn

Comment: Final trip takes more like 5-7 days (14thish through 21stish) which is typical for a Hohmann transfer from low Earth orbit to the Moon's distance.    Apollo burned more delta-v on departure to cut things down to three.

Comment: @notovny, you're right, I counted around three days to reach the distance of the moon, but it then took anouther couple to be captured. However, the free return was more the reason for Apollos extra speed.

Comment: @TheRocketfan India really doesn't have a 24-7 monitoring/communication/telemetry network so they need extra time to get everything checked and done. When China launched Chang'e 4, they had 5 ships and a dozen ground stations spread across the globe to support it and even launched a relay satellite towards moon's L2 specifically for Chang'e.  With such a tight budget, India is doing their moon mission more or less like others doing a Mars mission.

Comment: @user3528438: I would guess that if there's any possible imprecision in any of the burns, it may be difficult to precisely measure the new orbits until the craft has passed the point where one would want the next burn to start.  If one measures two nearby passes without any commanded acceleration between them, then it will be possible to know precisely when the engines should be used on the thir orbit.

Comment: @user3528438 As I understand it that's one of the reasons Chandrayaan 3 has a NASA retroreflector on top -- that was the minimum amount of hardware that they could take that would make it a "joint" effort which gives them access to our Deep Space Network. (And it's a fully passive piece of equipment, so they can still say all the functional pieces are Indian-made)

Comment: (to a space newbie) what an incredibly *unintuitive* trajectory! (I'd have assumed approximately a straight line!). Thanks for making the animated gif!

Comment: @stevec Orbital mechanics are a little mindbending until you actually _feel_ them.  If I could, I'd like to recommend to you the game "Kerbal Space Program".  Once you're comfortable with the Oberth effect as shown in the animation, try launching in an equatorial orbit and shifting to a polar one once in space.  That's a real thinker.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Do you have a reference for the *"joint effort"* statement? Why would'nt NASA give access to DSN for a price?

Comment: @AdamBarnes, you not only could, but absolutely *can* suggest KSP. I admit I did not have much patience for it, but I did play the first missions including the ones where you transfer a satellite to something very much like another planet or moon (can't recall). This one mission alone, which took me quite few hours, really taught me more about space travel than any of the copious SciFi books or pub-sci magazines I had read in the decades before that. Since then, I get strong urges of having to laugh relatively hard when seeing space flight depicted in movies...

Comment: @AJN I don't have a specific source. I think Scott Manley mentioned that the reflector gave ISRO access to the DSN for this mission, but I'm not sure what the politics behind it would be.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym [found it](https://youtu.be/hP0GbRNGMLk?t=454) thanks.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym and off we go! [Does a "partnership" with NASA offer advantages for deep space network (DSN) usage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/64004/12102)

Comment: @uhoh I would have liked to know if that is indeed the case, Scott isn't giving any sources there. DSN support was there for MOM and would be there for Aditya-L1 and both of them don't have any NASA payload..

Comment: @Ohsin I'm no expert and I think that's interesting enough to be posted as a new question. It is possible that ISRO simply paid for DSN support, or traded it for communications assistance with a NASA mission just for example. Or there's parts to the story that have been less-than-accurately and completely reported. I think the answer will be interesting!